# ActionController::UnknownFormat for respond_with

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have returned to my ruby on rails project to find that I am getting:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

error for a very simple line of code:

```
    respond_with(allMatches)
```

The allMatches hash is defined as:

```
        allMatches = {  "matchesProposed"   => proposedMatchAndNeedsActionObjects,
                        "matchesReceived"   => receivedMatchAndNeedsActionObjects,
                        "scheduledMatches"  => scheduledMatches}
```

I have declared at the class level:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :json
```

The code has been functioning just fine, until today - no changes!  Any thoughts?

Comment: Could be a conflict inside `allMatches`?

Answer (score 3):

The error `ActionController::UnknownFormat` is raised when there is a request in a format that is not specified in `respond_to` or `respond_with`.

Since you did not provide any further information and just minimal code examples, you will have to keep [digging yourself](http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/).